# Earned Steward badge twice for the same queue

Tags: bug, review, badges

Just like the title suggests: I was just awarded the Steward badge for Close Votes & Low Quality Posts, although I already got them like 6 months ago. My guess is this is a bug, as they are meant to be awarded once for each queue.

Comment: That's nothing. Today, I earned **all** 6 steward badges. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: A large number of users just re-earned some of their Steward badges: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/228.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You currently have 99 Steward badges, that’s incredible!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a bug; it's part of an update to the review queues. You now get one Steward badge for every 1,000 reviews in a single queue. For more details, see [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times -- backfill details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. The badge description will be updated shortly.

Comment: Hmm not sure how I feel about this. But thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I guess the closest analog is the Socratic badge.